# How to set height of zurb's orbit slider in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slider, zurb-foundation

I am using the zurb foundation rails gem for a new app and it works perfectly, except that the orbit slider changes height depending on an images size.

I'd like to set a default height of 500px, but I'm unsure how.  The JS and CSS options [provided](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/orbit.html) don't offer the ability to change height, and doing it in the view with html doesn't work either.

Could anyone tell me how I could provide a fixed height to my slider for all images?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The container of the slides seem to be controlled by this class div: orbit-slides-container

So I added that div to my layout.css.scss file with the height attribute:

```
  .orbit-slides-container {

  height: 500px;

   }
```

It is important that my application.css have the layout.css.scss included as I do not included it elsewhere.   Here is a snippit of that:

```
 *= require foundation_and_overrides
 *= require layout
 */
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Also I "think" that the height will be automatically set to the largest image you have by default.  So if you make all of your images the same height/width the default for orbit will be that.  I posted a basic example of foundation 4 orbit on github and on heroku.  Github is here: https://github.com/akkdio/orbit  heroku is here: http://arcane-depths-4560.herokuapp.com/task/index